# Does equation $xy(x+y)(x-y)=10z^2$ have nonzero integer solutions?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Supposing that solution exists, I've found that $x$, $y$, $(x+y)$, $(x-y)$ should be pairwise coprime numbers, and hence $x$ and $y$ are coprime of different parity. And after that I can not make any step further.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but $(\pm a,\pm a,0)$ are certainly solutions. :D

Comment: No, I need every cofactor of the left part to be nonzero )

Comment: I you had the simpler $xy = 10 z^2,$ you would still be able to assume $x,y$ coprime, and then have several cases: $x = 10 s^2, y = t^2.$ Next $x = 5 s^2, y = 2 t^2,$ and so on. Your version is worse. The point is if pairwise coprime numbers multiply to become a square, each is a square, once they are all known to be positive

Comment: Oh: computer run suggests impossibility.

Comment: If $(x,y,z)$ is a solution, then so is $(x+y,x-y,2z)$.

Comment: Following my last comment, the next iteration is that $(2x,2y,4z)$ is a solution. So that calls into question the claim that $x$ and $y$ are of different parity. Or, if you really did establish that, then here is your contradiction.

Comment: Or maybe you are saying that you may _assume_ $x$ and $y$ are coprime of different parity because you can reduce other cases to that case?

Comment: @alex could you please look at the revised problems I computed? Interesting the number of solutions I could find (in a reasonable time on the computer) goes up with prime factor number of the multiplier.

Comment: Idea: if we fix a value for either $x$ or $y$ and consider this as an equation the remaining two variables (if the fixed value is non-zero), so this question is asking for the integral points on a family of elliptic curves. Not sure if this viewpoint helps.

Comment: @WillJagy You can see my comment in your data, in that the solution sets pair up. Like for 2730: $(10,3,z)$ with $(13,7,z)$ and $(13,8,z)$ with $(21,5,z)$.

Comment: @alex, good. I did a separate experiment with multiplier $1.$ I think there may be a complete proof available, as requiring the $x,y,x+y$ are squares is very strong, Pythagorean triple.

Comment: @Alex, yes, I mean I may assume $x$ and $y$ are coprime of different parity because other cases can be reduced to that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original question is equivalent to asking whether $10$ is a congruent number - which it isn't.

With a general multiplier $N$, we have
\begin{equation*}
xy(x+y)(x-y)=Nz^2
\end{equation*}

Define $t=x/y$ and $w=z/y^2$ giving
\begin{equation*}
t(t+1)(t-1)=Nw^2
\end{equation*}
and then define $s=Nt$ and $r=N^2w$ leading to
\begin{equation*}
r^2=s^3-N^2s
\end{equation*}
which is the elliptic curve for the congruent number problem.

Non-zero solutions only come from curves with rank greater than zero. This includes $N=5,6,7$ which give curves of rank $1$. $N=2730$ gives a curve of rank $2$ using Denis Simon's ellrank code.

Comment: Oh, that's very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of interesting. I replaced the $10$ with $2730$ in order to get at least one solution, it suddenly gave many:

```
Thu Dec  7 15:53:49 PST 2017
        10         3                2730  =   2 3 5 7 13
        13         7               10920  =   2^3 3 5 7 13
        13         8               10920  =   2^3 3 5 7 13
        14         1                2730  =   2 3 5 7 13
        15        13               10920  =   2^3 3 5 7 13
        21         5               43680  =   2^5 3 5 7 13
      1573       128        494892478080  =   2^7 3^5 5 7 11^2 13 17^2
      1694      1681        124939064250  =   2 3^3 5^3 7 11^2 13 41^2
      1701      1445       1979569912320  =   2^9 3^5 5 7 11^2 13 17^2
      3375        13        499756257000  =   2^3 3^3 5^3 7 11^2 13 41^2
      3610      3267      27819510288570  =   2 3^3 5 7^3 11^2 13 19^2 23^2
      6877       343     111278041154280  =   2^3 3^3 5 7^3 11^2 13 19^2 23^2
Thu Dec  7 15:55:10 PST 2017
```

===================================================

Multiplier set to $6$

```
Thu Dec  7 16:47:57 PST 2017
         2         1                   6  =   2 3
         3         1                  24  =   2^3 3
        25        24               29400  =   2^3 3 5^2 7^2
        49         1              117600  =   2^5 3 5^2 7^2
      2738       529      10452831898806  =   2 3^3 11^2 23^2 37^2 47^2
      3267      2209      41811327595224  =   2^3 3^3 11^2 23^2 37^2 47^2
Thu Dec  7 16:50:07 PST 2017
```

============================================================

Multiplier set to $7,$ and checked for $0<y < x < 11000$

```
Thu Dec  7 16:56:20 PST 2017
        16         9               25200  =   2^4 3^2 5^2 7
        25         7              100800  =   2^6 3^2 5^2 7
Thu Dec  7 16:58:08 PST 2017
```

================================================================

Multiplier set to  $14$

```
Thu Dec  7 17:15:36 PST 2017
         8         1                 504  =   2^3 3^2 7
         9         7                2016  =   2^5 3^2 7
      4225      2016     117426776594400  =   2^5 3^2 5^2 7 13^2 47^2 79^2
      6241      2209     469707106377600  =   2^7 3^2 5^2 7 13^2 47^2 79^2
```

=========================================

Answer (score 0):

The reference to congruent numbers settles the original question and similar questions with $10$ replaced with $N$. There is an even more general result relating to division polynomials and discrete analogs of Weierstrass sigma and Jacobi theta functions. This is given in my work at 
[Weierstrass Elliptic Function Polynomials](http://grail.eecs.csuohio.edu/~somos/wxyz.html).
In brief, I construct four  sequences $\, (w_n,x_n,y_n,z_n) \,$ such that
$\, (x_n/x_0)^2 - (y_n/y_0)^2 = (x_1^2-y_1^2) (w_n/w_1)^2, \,$
$\, (z_n/z_0)^2 - (y_n/y_0)^2 = (z_1^2-y_1^2) (w_n/w_1)^2, \,$
$\, (z_n/z_0)^2 - (z_n/z_0)^2 = (z_1^2-x_1^2) (w_n/w_1)^2  \,$ for all integer $\, n.$ They satisfy recursions such as
$\, w_{n+1}w_{n-1}x_0^2 = w_n^2 x_1^2 - x_n^2 w_1^2, \,$ and $\, 
 x_{n+1}x_{n-1}x_0^2 = x_n^2 x_1^2 -
 (x_1^2-y_1^2)(x_1^2-z_1^2)(w_n/w_1)^2 x_0^4.  $

For an numerical example we let
 $$  x_0 \!=\! y_0 \!=\! z_0 \!=\! w_1 \!=\! y_1 \!=\! 1 \quad \text{and} \quad
 x_1 \!=\! \sqrt{2},\,  z_1 \!=\! \sqrt{3},\, x_1^2-y_1^2 \!=\! 1,\, z_1^2-y_1^2 \!=\! 2,\,
 z_1^2-x_1^2 \!=\! 1.  $$
In this particular example we have
 $$ x_n^2-y_n^2 = w_n^2, \,\, z_n^2-y_n^2 = 2w_n^2, \,\, z_n^2-x_n^2 = w_n^2,
  \,\, x_n^2-w_n^2 = y_n^2, \,\, x_n^2+w_n^2 = z_n^2. $$
This implies $\, x_n^2 w_n^2 (x_n^2+w_n^2)(x_n^2-w_n^2) = (w_nx_ny_nz_n)^2
 = w_{2n}^2 /4. \,$
Because $\, w_n \,$ is a divisibility sequence, we have $\, w_{2n} = w_2t_n \,$
where $\, w_2 = 2\sqrt{6} \,$ and $\, t_n \,$ is an integer sequence. Thus,
 $\, w_{2n}^2/4 \!=\! 6\,t_n^2. $ This gives a sequence of solutions to
 $\, x^2 w^2(x^2+w^2)(x^2-w^2) = 6\,t^2. \,$  The four sequences
 $\, w_n^2, x_n^2, y_n^2, z_n^2 \,$ are integer sequences.